# Best approach to store a set of static String values

Tags: java, performance, collections, singleton

I have a requirement to retrieve query params lets say **clId**,**clCtx** and **clName** from an odata uri and use them throughout the program across many classes. Retrieving the query params is an expensive process each time in our customised client framework. What is the best approach to retrieve and store the params once per request and utilise the same throughout the program?

My thoughts were to create a singleton class with a static java map as below. For the first time I can retrieve and store them in a map to use them later.

Also Would like to know Is my approach has any issues like memory leak or drawbacks.

```
public class ClientContainer {

  private static Map<String,String> clientMap;
  private static ClientContainer instance;

  private ClientContainer(){}

 public static ClientContainer getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new ClientContainer();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private void updateClientMap(HashMap<String,String> clientMap){
    if(this.clientMap==null){
        this.clientMap =clientMap;
    }
  }

  private HashMap<String,String> getClientMap(){
     return this.clientMap;
   }
}
```

Comment: Using a map is also expensive if you already know the parameter names, and they are not dynamic. I guess, I would rather use the good old bean, it is fast and clean. Also, depending on the implementation behind your system you might be just replacing a map by another map, in which case the suggested approach would be harmful.

Comment: Victor, The query params which I retrieve is not a plain Java map. There are about 4 transformations(scala data to Java data) to be done to get a Java Map with those params. I have to repeat this process 10-11 times in different classes.As this affects the performance of program, Instead I need a efficient and optimized way to store them up some where in program as one-time step and fetch them in an easy way whenever I need them.

Comment: How many are the parameters? do know know their names ahead of time? if they are few and you know them, I would use a bean.

Comment: in that case, I like your solution, but you like to check if you map calls for volatile and you be even more comfortable if besides being volatile was immutable and final.considering that you add a client key as well.

Comment: Thanks Victor for your suggestion. It would rather be good to use a bean, as my approach is buggy and may cause memory leaks in real time which is even more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

> Also Would like to know Is my approach has any issues like memory leak
>   or drawbacks.

1) Your `ClientContainer` class stores only the parameters for one client.
You use a `Map<String,String>` (values by param) in and not a `Map<Client, Map<String, String>>` (values by param and all that by client).
As you can instantiate a single time the class with the singleton pattern you are so stuck to store data not more than for one client request.

2) The lifespan of the requests (param-value) will be endless in this way.
The `Map` will indeed never be garbage collected as this is referenced by the singleton instance that has never a chance to be garbage collected too.

So if you keep the singleton pattern you should at least consider the `key-values` according to the client and you should also think to clean the cache at each time that a request was completely handled to avoid memory leak.

But If I was you, I probably would use another solution:

- either I would create the Map as a local variable a single time : at the time where I receive the request and then I would pass it explicitly to each method that needs that.
- or I would use [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to store the Map if each request is handled by a specific thread.

Note that I prefer the first way that exposes clearly the dependency of the method.
Note also that using a `Map` is not necessary the best thing if the number of fields to use is stable and known : using a custom class may be much clearer, readable and more robust.

Comment: Thanks David for a clear explanation. This was really helpful.

Comment: @Lokesh Reddy I am glad if it was helpful for you.

Comment: up for that: either I would create the Map as a local variable a single time : at the time where I receive the request and then I would pass it explicitly to each method that needs that.

Comment: the centralized cache as described in this answer would also benefit from being volatile, possibly final, with extra logic for assuring the map is mutable.  the map it self does not call for being synchronized, as long it is read only.

Comment: @Victor I agree for all but "the map it self does not call for being synchronized, as long it is read only."  From the moment where you change the state of the map (to add parameters of a client request or to clear the cache of a client request) you may (at least in theory) corrupt the map state if you have race condition in the map access.  Synchronization is so required to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks again! Victor and David ,both your inputs helps me in deciding a best way as per my context. Up for both :)

Comment: @Lokesh Reddy  "Up" means "I upvoted" :) You cannot for the moment (you don't have enough reputation) but whatever thanks for you good words :)

Comment: likewise, good luck. but just to clarify, yes you need sync if 2 levels. but for the last level not. on that case there are 2 maps and I was referring to the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ClientContainer class in multithreading environment, then make sense to make getInstance() method thread-safe in order to avoid duplication of constructor. To avoid of memory leaks you can use WeakHashMap instead of HashMap.